# Is a DTC necessary for a SQL 2008 R2 Cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, cluster-computing, msdtc

I have a 2 node SQL 2008 R2 cluster up and running fine.  SQL1 is the main server and SQL2 takes over when 1 goes offline.  Tested...working great.  My question is regarding the Distributed Transaction Coordinator's role.  I do NOT have a DTC configured and everything seems fine.

Why would I need the DTC?  What situations would require one?

Thanks,

MJ

Answer (score 0):

In my case - no.  I'm running a SQL cluster (2008 R2 RU6) without DTC and everything seems fine.